# Ifelse statement applied across list

Tags: r, if-statement, logic

Trying to match a column against a list and return 'match' if there is a match using `ifelse`

I got close with this try:

```
> df$b <- ifelse(grepl(df1,df$value), 'match', NA)


Warning message:
In grepl(df1, df$value) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

 value b    
   <int> <chr>
 1     1 NA   
 2     2 NA   
 3     3 NA   
 4     4 NA   
 5     5 match
 6     6 NA   
 7     7 NA   
 8     8 NA   
 9     9 NA   
10    10 NA
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
value b 
   <int> <chr>
 1     1 NA   
 2     2 NA   
 3     3 NA   
 4     4 NA   
 5     5 match
 6     6 match   
 7     7 match   
 8     8 match   
 9     9 match   
10    10 match
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: edited the question after marked duplicate. I would have never been able to answer my question from seeing the other answers. I also wasn't able to find that question.

Comment: You are right in saying that I should have edited before marking as duplicate. Anyway, the warning came from `df$value == df1`, this is what was written before your edit. The dupe answers to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `%in%` operator :

```
df$b <- ifelse(df$value %in% df1,'match',NA)
```

Comment: Thanks, that totally works.